# En Pyhton ¿Cómo puedo combinar 3 archivos Excel a uno solo, pero estando los datos de cada archivo en una hoja diferente?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Con un código de Python usando la librería de pandas he podido hacer que se generen 3 archivos Excel con datos en cada uno.

Pero lo que quiero hacer y no encuentro manera es que esos 3 archivos Excel se combinen en uno solo **y** que los datos de cada uno de esos archivos esté en una **hoja diferente** de ese único Excel.

Por favor ¿Cómo puedo? He probado de varias maneras pero lo máximo que consigo es combinar los Excel pero siempre quedándose todo mezclado en una misma hoja.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-merge-multiple-excel-files-into-a-single-files-with-python/
Aquí te dejo una página que enseña como se hace

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: agrega lo que has intentado toda pregunta debe tener un [example]

Answer (score 1):

Para escribir a diferentes hojas de un mismo excel debes crear un `ExcelWriter`. Un ejemplo de código mínimo:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "numeros": [1,2,3,4],
    "mensajes": ["hola", "que", "tal", "estas"]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Nombre": ["Juan", "Ana", "Ramón", "Adela"],
    "Edad": [4,5,6,7]
})

with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx") as xls:
    df1.to_excel(xls, sheet_name="Hoja 1")
    df2.to_excel(xls, sheet_name="Hoja 2")
```

Resultado:

### [image: Hoja 1]

[image: Hoja 2]

**Nota** Además de `pandas` debes tener instalada la biblioteca `openpyxl`